# Vue for loop returning one value

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm getting an array of contractors from the database. I want it such that when the salary of one contractor is accepted, then the remaining contractors are removed from the DOM.

```
<div v-for="contractor in contacted_contractors" :key="contractor.id">

    <form @submit.prevent="acceptSalary(contractor.user_id, contractor.maintenance_id)">
       <button>Accept salary</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

This is the method that attempts to get rid of the remaining contractors after the salary of one has been accepted

```
  async acceptSalary (user_id, maintenance_id) {
            this.accept_salary.maintenance_id = maintenance_id;
            this.accept_salary.user_id = user_id;
            await axios.post('/api/maintenances/respond/budget', this.accept_salary).then(response => {
                    this.salary_accepted = true

                    for (let i = 0; i < this.contacted_contractors.length; i++) {
                        if(this.contacted_contractors[i].user_id == this.accept_salary.user_id){

                        this.show_contractor = true
                        }

                        else{
                        this.show_contractor = false

                        }
                    return this.show_contractor
                    }

        })
        .catch(error => {})
        }
```

The problem is that when I run the `show_contractor` in the HTML it returns the same value for all the contractors, And I want it to return true for the contractor whose salary has been accepted and false for all the others.

```
<div v-for="contractor in contacted_contractors" :key="contractor.id">
    {{ show_contractor }}
    <form @submit.prevent="acceptSalary(contractor.user_id, contractor.maintenance_id)">
       <button>Accept salary</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: What about a method that handles filtering the accepted contractor and then running the results of that filter in your template?

Comment: Maybe stupid question but: Are you sure that the button will submit the form?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, it seems that `show_contractor` is a data property of your vue component that contains this `v-for` which renders contractors. It's not scoped to single contractors, so it's the same value for all of them.

Like @rguttersohn commented, I recommend a computed property which filters your list of contractors.

```
<div v-for="contractor in accepted_contractors">
  {{contractor}}
</div>
```

```js
accepted_contractors() {
  return this.contacted_contractors.filter(contractor => {
    return contractor.user_id === this.accept_salary.user_id
  })
}
```